# how to properly declare a qvariantlist and initialize it so i can put my custom object/class into it by appending

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

i cannot figure out how to use a qvariantlist from all the examples i find
i need to stuff filenames-sizes-checksum for multiple files in a csv file and be able to search through them later here is the part where i'm stuck

```
    QVariantList vlFiles;


if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return vlFiles;

    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();

       QList<QByteArray> query = line.split(';');

        struct information i1;
        i1.fileName = query.at(0);
        i1.fileSize = query.at(1);
        QString ts = query.at(2);
        ts.replace("\n", "");
        i1.md5Sum = ts;
        vlFiles.append(i1)//stuck here

mainwindow.cpp:452:21: error: no matching member function for call to 'append'
qlist.h:204:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'struct information' to 'const QVariant' for 1st argument
qlist.h:205:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'struct information' to 'const QList<QVariant>' for 1st argument
```

Thanks to Igor's suggestion I was able to get past this point but now I want to retrieve the data back from the qvariantlist and display each item and its 3 sub strings which are saved as a custom struct class...

```
QVariantList vlFilesToDownload = 
getDownloadList("downloadlist.txt");

for(QVariantList::const_iterator it = 
vlFilesToDownload.begin();
    it!=vlFilesToDownload.end();
    ++it)
{ 
    if(it->)
```

> **part** i'm stuck on, i have tried all the options from the auto
> complete menu and cannot get any useful data from the iterator, i
> must have to somehow cast the iterator to the QVariantList and my
> struct class *pulls hair out*

```
   { 
       //use qdebug to print the list items and data to console
    } 
};
```

Comment: Try `vlFiles.append(QVariant::fromValue(i1));` Your structure must have its metadata registered with [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

Comment: Got that working, thank you for that Igor, any idea how to cast an item from the qvariantlist back to my custom class that contains a struct with 3 QStrings for data?

Comment: `vlFiles.first().value<information>()`

Comment: Not sure why the other person deleted their extensive comment, I just went to go over it and its been removed, it looked like a juicy answer too, thats a dissappointment should have left it